# Get last value from a minute

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following table

```
+-----------------------+-------+----------+---------+----------+
|date                   |curency|high_price|low_price|last_price|
+-----------------------+-------+----------+---------+----------+
|2014-01-16 16:01:42.000|2      |24.98     |23.9     |24.2      |
+-----------------------+-------+----------+---------+----------+
|2014-01-16 16:01:32.000|2      |24.98     |23.9     |24.12202  |
+-----------------------+-------+----------+---------+----------+
|2014-01-16 16:01:22.000|2      |24.98     |23.9     |24.12202  |
+-----------------------+-------+----------+---------+----------+
|2014-01-16 16:01:12.000|2      |24.98     |23.9     |24.21626  |
+-----------------------+-------+----------+---------+----------+
|2014-01-16 16:01:02.000|2      |24.98     |23.9     |24.11102  |
+-----------------------+-------+----------+---------+----------+
|2014-01-16 16:00:52.000|2      |24.98     |23.9     |24.21628  |
+-----------------------+-------+----------+---------+----------+
|2014-01-16 16:00:42.000|2      |24.98     |23.9     |24.2      |
+-----------------------+-------+----------+---------+----------+
|2014-01-16 16:00:32.000|2      |24.98     |23.9     |24.2      |
+-----------------------+-------+----------+---------+----------+
```

And i use the following query to group by time intervals for example for 15 minutes :

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT 
        last_price,
        high_price,
        low_price, 
        dateadd(MINUTE, datediff(MINUTE, 0,[date])/1*1,0) AS SERVERTIME
    FROM 
        m_cPrice 
    WHERE 
        curency=2 
    GROUP BY 
        last_price,
        high_price,
        low_price,
        datediff(MINUTE, 0,[date])/1*1 
)
SELECT 
    last_price,
    high_price,
    low_price , 
    dateadd(MINUTE, datediff(MINUTE, 0,SERVERTIME)/1*1,0) as STIME 
FROM 
    x 
WHERE 
    DATEPART(MINUTE,SERVERTIME)%15=0
ORDER BY 
    STIME DESC
```

problem is that it get all the values from that minute or interval and i need only the last value of not all of them

Thanks in advance

Comment: doesnt work with MAX already checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work, but bit tricky to tell given the limited scope of sample data:

```
declare @t table([date] datetime,curency /* sic */ int, high_price decimal(38,5),
                 low_price decimal(38,5), last_price decimal(38,5))
insert into @t([date],curency, high_price,  low_price,   last_price) values
('2014-01-16T16:01:42.000',2,24.98,23.9,24.2    ),
('2014-01-16T16:01:32.000',2,24.98,23.9,24.12202),
('2014-01-16T16:01:22.000',2,24.98,23.9,24.12202),
('2014-01-16T16:01:12.000',2,24.98,23.9,24.21626),
('2014-01-16T16:01:02.000',2,24.98,23.9,24.11102),
('2014-01-16T16:00:52.000',2,24.98,23.9,24.21628),
('2014-01-16T16:00:42.000',2,24.98,23.9,24.2    ),
('2014-01-16T16:00:32.000',2,24.98,23.9,24.2    )

;With Periods as (
    select *,
        DATEADD(minute,((DATEDIFF(minute,0,[date])/1)*1),0) as DatePeriod
    from @t
), Ordered as (
    select *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DatePeriod
                            ORDER BY [date] desc) as rn
    from Periods
)
select DatePeriod,last_price
from Ordered where rn = 1
```

The `Periods` CTE is the one that determines which period each `[date]` value belongs to. I initially had `/15)*15)` to get 15 minute intervals, as per your narrative, before spotting that you've only given us data for two minutes, so it's currently `/1)*1)` (which could be completely removed now).

This gives us:

```
DatePeriod              last_price
----------------------- ---------------------------------------
2014-01-16 16:00:00.000 24.21628
2014-01-16 16:01:00.000 24.20000
```